# Almost uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

$f : [a;b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $a < \alpha < \beta < b$. $f$ has continous derivative on $(\alpha; \beta)$. $f_n(x) = n(f(x + \frac{1}{n}) - f(x))$. Show almost uniform convergence of $f_n$ on $(\alpha; \beta)$. I noticed that $f_n(x) = \frac{f(x + \frac{1}{n}) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow f'$ but what to do next?

Comment: Since the derivative is continuous, you should be able to see that the convergence is uniform on $[\alpha+\varepsilon, \beta-\varepsilon]$ for every $\varepsilon$. Does that help?

Comment: @AidanSims Not really. On compact interval $f'$ is bounded. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Well $f$ has continuous derivative on $(\alpha,\beta)$, so it's continuous on $(\alpha,\beta)$ and hence uniformly continuous on every closed subinterval $I_\varepsilon := [\alpha+\varepsilon, \beta-\varepsilon]$. Likewise $f$ is uniformly continuous on each $I_\varepsilon$, and $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $I_\varepsilon$. Since $I_\varepsilon$ is compact, the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $I_\varepsilon$ guarantees uniform convergence.

Comment: Why pointwise convergence of $f_n$ on $I_\varepsilon$ guarantees uniform convergence?

Comment: I think it should be proved that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{ sup\{ f_{n|I_\varepsilon} - f'_{|\varepsilon}\} } =0$

Comment: Sorry, yes that's the idea. You want to apply Dini's theorem, which applies to the sequence $\limsup_n |f_n - f'|$ because it's a decreasing sequence. I had in my head that the sequence $f_n$ was already decreasing.

Comment: Why it's a decreasing sequence?

Comment: $\sup_{j \ge n} |f_n(x) - f'(x)| \le \sup_{j \ge n-1} |f_n(x) - f'(x)|$ because the supremum is over a smaller set. But now I'm trying to convince myself that this defines a sequence of continuous functions in the first place. I don't seem to be having a great day here. :-)

Comment: I don't want to apply Dini's theorem. Just $\lim_{n \to \infty}{ sup\{ f_{n|I_\varepsilon} - f'_{|\varepsilon}\} } =0$ guarantees thesis.

Comment: But let's consider every $I_\varepsilon$ on which $f'$ is negative (or non-negative). We can apply Dini's theorem on every such $I_\varepsilon$. Is it enough?

Comment: I don't think that's enough - if it were, the argument should apply quite generally, and you wouldn't need the monotonicity hypothesis on Dini's theorem (which you do). Perhaps try proving that the $f_n$ are equicontinuous?